# Kotlin get generic type class using reified

Tags: android, kotlin

I just started using Kotlin instead of Java and i'm struggling to make refied work to retrieve a generic type class. Here my use case

```
abstract class BaseDataFragment<VM : BaseViewModel> : BaseFragment()
{
    @Inject
    protected lateinit var viewModelProvider: ViewModelProvider
    protected lateinit var viewModel: VM

    @CallSuper
    override fun init(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        viewModel = viewModelProvider.get(getViewModelClass())
    }

    private inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> getViewModelClass():Class<T> = T::class.java
}
```

Unfortunately i get an error from `getViewModelClass()`:

> Cannot use 'VM' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.

Is there anyway to make it work?

Comment: do you want to get the generic type VM at runtime? This is not possible with reified

Comment: Yes that's my goal, i thought reified was supposed to solve that, i guess i was wrong, so i'll get back to my old java workaround with a abstract method implemented on each fragment subclass to retrieve generic type Class, anyway thx!

Comment: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/reified-type-parameters-in-classes/1567 this might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reified` is not a magical workaround for type erasure. An instance of a generic class on the JVM does not carry any information about the type parameter it was instantiated with. Because the information is not there, `reified` cannot be used to access it.

`reified` only works when the type information is known at the call site at compile time, which is not the case here.

If you want to be able to do that, you need to store a `Class` or `KClass` as a property of your class, or indeed to create a virtual method for obtaining the `Class` or `KClass` instance for each derived class.

Comment: Wouldn't it act wrong with types, parameterized by primitives? As described [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/reified-type-parameters-in-classes/1567/4)

Comment: Kotlin does not support types parameterized by primitives. If you use something like `Int` as a type parameter, from the Java point of view the type parameter will be `java.lang.Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with retrieving java class of generic type in Kotlin and finally failed. And I found another way to satisfy this requirement.

```
abstract class BaseDataFragment: BaseFragment() {
    protected lateinit var viewModel: BaseViewModel
    fun initFragment() {
        viewModel = initVM()
    }
    open fun initVM(): BaseViewModel {
        return viewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::java.class)
    }
}
```

inherited class can override this function to implement owner ViewModel.