# Cannot use R as reified type parameter use a class instead in abstract class Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I have a few classes that do almost the same thing, so I wanted to create an abstract class to remove the duplication. The simplest way to see is through the small example below:

I have the classes A and B as:

```
class A {
  fun create(
        request: RA,
      ): ResponseEntity<RA> {
        return foo(RA::class)
  }

}

class B {
  fun create(
        request: RB,
    ): ResponseEntity<RB> {
        return foo(RB::class)
  }

}
```

Where RA and RB both inherit from RX.

I want to create an abstract class to remove this duplication. So I tried something like this:

```
abstract class C <R: RX> {
  fun create(
        request: R,
    ): ResponseEntity<R> {
        return foo(getKClass())
  }

  abstract fun getKClass() : KClass<R>
}

class A : C() {

  fun aMethod() {
    println("Hello world!")
  }

  override fun getKClass() : KClass<A> {
    return A::class
  }
}

class B : C() {

  fun bMethod() {
    println("Hello world2!")
  }

  override fun getKClass() : KClass<B> {
    return B::class
  }

}
```

So that then Class A and Class B are able to extend Class C and the duplication is removed. The issue is that since R in the Class C is generic I get the error `cannot use R as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.` I tried a few things such as making the `create` function inline and using reified types in Class C. Is there anything else I should try or just keep the duplication?

I just noticed this answer from this user ([Kotlin get generic type class using reified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48955699/kotlin-get-generic-type-class-using-reified)), so I tried to have a function in class A and class B, that returned the KClass and then use that in the abstract class C, but also to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: Could you attach the code with KClass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the answer to the question you linked states:

> `reified` only works when the type information is known at the call site
>   at compile time, which is not the case here.
>
> If you want to be able to do that, you need to store a Class or KClass
>   as a property of your class, or indeed to create a virtual method for
>   obtaining the Class or KClass instance for each derived class.

So you could you implement the first suggestion (store a Class or KClass as a property of your class) with something like this:

```
abstract class C<R : RX>(private val clazz: KClass<R>) {
    fun create(request: R): ResponseEntity<R> {
        return foo(clazz)
    }
}

class A : C<RA>(RA::class)

class B : C<RB>(RB::class)
```

If you prefer the second suggestion (create a virtual method for obtaining the Class or KClass) then replace withe `clazz` constructor parameter with a protected abstract method or property instead. (Though a constructor parameter here is probably a bit less code to achieve the same result and is arguably the more idiomatic way to do it.)

I've assumed that you have an `RA` and `RB` as well as `A` and `B`. Is that correct? I wasn't quite clear from your two code snippets above.